# Visual Studio 2017 xaml designer not available

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2017

Using Visual Studio Professional 2017 (Release 15.2 26430.16), when I open a xaml file for a desktop UI that I have developed, I can no longer see the xaml designer (I only see the raw xaml code). This is new behaviour and may be due to me having a system clean-out, so maybe I removed an SDK that I need or something like that?

Are there any Visual Studio error logs I can check for warnings etc?

[image: XAML Editor]

Comment: Do you have your _XAML Designer_ enabled under Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> General?

Comment: Did you find any solution please tell me

Comment: In case anyone doing Xamarin has this problem, I found out that Xamarin doesn't support XAML designer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the Visual Studio 2017 Installer, I selected all of the SDKs and installed the missing ones. This did not fix the problem by itself, but a subsequent 'repair' from the Visual Studio 2017 Installer (available from the 'hamburger' drop-down) did.

Sometimes, adding or removing SDKs from the Installer toggles the 'Enable XAML Designer' check box under Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> General (or perhaps it was the repair step that turned this back on), so ensure that this is checked.

Comment: accept this as answer for your own question as this worked out for u

Answer (score 30):

Frankly, your situation is different than mine. In my situation, it was because of Resharper. Maybe this may useful for someone else.
What to do is checking **Resharper Options > Enviroment > Performance Guide > Disable XAML Designer**.

It must be set to **"Ignore"** or **"Show in Status Bar"**. Otherwise, it will always disable XAML Designer.

Comment: Thanks @basfar. This was the case. ReSharper could at least show some popup with warning.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure XAML Designer is enabled.

Tools -> Options -> XAML Designer -> General -> Enable XAML Designer

Answer (score 5):

I couldn't get the designer to work, but I found an alternate solution posted [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/70095/xaml-previewer-for-xamarin-), posted by [@DamianSuess](https://forums.xamarin.com/profile/DamianSuess)

> Use the **View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer** menu in
> Visual Studio to open the preview window. Use the Window > New
> Vertical Tab Group menu to position it side-by-side.

forms-not-show-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 5):

I know this issue is tagged as WPF but I had a similar issue for Xamarin Forms.

What solved this issue for me:

1. Right Click the xaml file
2. Select "Open With..."
3. Select Xamarin.Forms Previewer [image: List item]
4. Click OK
5. Optionally, you can set the Xamarin.Forms Previewer as the default for xaml files

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have correctly installed the Windows 10 SDK, there are 3-4 versions of the SDK, the error you are talking about can also be a consequence of a incompatible sdk,
also reinstall the sdk related to your app, close every process related to Visual studio running in background while reinstalling the SDK.

Can you share a screenshot of the xaml designer page?

Comment: Thanks, I'll try adding back in the SDKs that I over zealously cleaned out

Comment: I have added back in all of the SDKs (including the Win 8.1 SDK), but this hasn't helped. Now attempting a 'repair' from the Visual Studio 2017 installer

Comment: It's strange Rob, there's not even the Designer tab in your editor windows. I think we are missing something here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, I found that opening the XAML in VS community did not work. However, if I choose file -> open -> project/solution and open the corresponding sln file, it works.