# visual Studio WPF xaml designer won't show up, even when enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, designer, visual-studio-designer

So I'm trying to load the XAML designer in visual Studio, and it won't show up, only the source editor shows up
[image]

I use the XAML WPF designer to make a lot of decisions, as I'm not on a team and do everything myself with this program including UI design so I tried to turn it back on, so in the settings I tried to turn it on
[image]
I set it to these settings and restarted visual studio and I still can't open it, can someone please help me load the designer?

thanks

Comment: Was it working before? Do you use Resharper (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48614951/1997232)) or something similar?

Comment: it was working before I loaded the project from a folder, I'm going to upload it to github so I moved some files, that's why I can't use the sln

Comment: So you didn't open project and just clicking xaml file or what?

Comment: @EverythingLeafwing Could you create a new wpf desktop application to check if the MainWindow has the XAML desinger? If it has, the problem may be in your project not settings in Visual studio.

Comment: I did and it did show up, as a last resort after the code stopped being compileable Ijust pasted the code into a new project

Comment: @EverythingLeafwing There may be problems with your process of copying the project. How did you copy the code to your new project?

Answer (score 0):

What is below your bottom bar in your screenshot? you should see the Design/XAML tabs to toggle between them, or mouse on the border to drag up the designer/xaml splitter.

[image: Design/XAML tabs]

Comment: trust me I checked for that. its that purple bar

Comment: yes, that is what I checked for, I can't find it, that's the problem

Answer (score 0):

I just started having this problem out of the blue -- the problem is the default editor for XAML pages has been changed somehow. To fix it, right-click the XAML file in Solution Explorer and select "Open With...". In the dialog, select "XAML Designer", then click "Set as Default". Click OK. The designer should appear alongside the XML view.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34442963)

Comment: This completely and precisely answers the question. Please elaborate so I can understand your review.